# Find a sequence of rational numbers converging with some properties

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a question: given a point $x_o\in \mathbb{R},$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$,  can I always find a sequence of rationals $q_n$ s.t. $|q_{n+1}-x_0|\le\frac{1}{k}|q_n-x_0|$?
My idea was to pick a $q_0\in\mathbb{Q}$, then choose any $q_1\in B_{\frac{q_0-x_0}{k}}(x_0)$ (since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense and $B_{\frac{q_0-x_0}{k}}(x_0)$ is open, $q_1$ exists), then any $q_2\in B_{\frac{q_1-x_0}{k}}(x_0)$ and so on. The problem  is that maybe axiom of choice is required? I don't need the exact sequence, I just need to know if I can use the fact that it exists. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: No axiom of choice is needed: use some explicit bijection $f:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb N$ and instead of "choosing" your $q_n$, take (among the candidates) the $q$ for which $f(q)$ is the smallest.

Comment: But this wouldn't have the property I asked for, right?

Comment: Yes it would. I said "among the candidates". I.e. for example instead of choosing *any* $q_1\in B_{\frac{q_0-x_0}{k}}(x_0),$ take *the one* which has the smallest image by $f,$ and so on.

Comment: You're right! Thank you :)